# why isn't this js code for finding derivative working?

Tags: javascript, debugging

When ran it gives an alert box with undefined written, Can you help me debug this code? I am unable to find the correct error you can check it and please help me. It must give the derivative at point `x=10` for `f(x)=x^2+1` by using smaller and smaller `h` till desired accuracy is reached.

```js
function f(x) {
  return x * x + 1;
}
var iter = [];
var h = 0;
var ddx = 0;
iter[0] = ((f(10 + h) - f(10)) / h);

function d_dx(p) {
  for (i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
    iter[i] = ((f(p + h) - f(p)) / h);
    if (iter[i] = iter[i - 1]) {
      break;
      var ddx = iter[i];
    } else {
      h = h / 2;
    }
  }
  return ddx;
}
console.log(d_dx(10));
```

Comment: voting to close this because questions asking for debugging help is generally considered off topic on SO

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt SO is for doubts and debugging is a doubt

Comment: FYI, debugging is not considered to be a doubt

Answer (score 0):

var ddx is not reachable after break. That's why it is returning undefined. And one more thing, you are using assignment instead of conditional expression.(correct comparison is - if (iter[i] == iter[i - 1])) )

You have used var ddx out of scope while you are returning the ddx.

Answer (score 0):

Your `iter` array will be `NaN`. `h` will be always `0` and you divide by 0.
`if (iter[i] = iter[i - 1])` statement is wrong, you should use `===` to compare values. You cannot use `break` in `if` if you want to loop this code multiple times. There are many mistakes in your code.